# Where does the AngularJS HTTP store objects when they are cached?

Tags: angularjs

I am reading the following in the documentation:

```
To enable caching, set the request configuration cache property to 
true (to use default cache) or to a custom cache object 
(built with $cacheFactory).
```

Can someone tell me. Where does the cache data get stored? Also what is the advantage in using $cacheFactory and **how do I use** a custom cache factory with HTTP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The data are stored in memory (e.g. in your browser)

2) You avoid doing multiple server request for the same resource (for example template files)

3) With: var `cache = $cacheFactory('yourCacheId');` you may create your own cache. The advatage of this could be, that you can clear the cache for specific resources ( `cache.removeAll` ).

Doku: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24cacheFactory)